# Java decryption from byte to text

Tags: java, byte

I want to write a java program which takes a text field with `byte` data. Output of my program should be `string`. How can I achieve that. Any inputs are appreciated.

Input is

> 85f960f0 82868260 f4f78486 60f8f6f

Output is string format like customer, hero, english..

I am planning to write a simple java program.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for missing out details first time. I am in learning stages now.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What's the input format?

Comment: Please add example expected inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide enough detail for a full answer. Assuming the fragment "85f960f0 82868260 f4f78486 60f8f6f" is the output you want...

- convert a byte array to hexadecimal string using [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) using the %x pattern within a loop.
- Use %02x to pad each octet to 2 digits if necessary
- if you need spaces every 8 characters you could do this by checking to see if the counter is divisible by 4 using the % operator.

For example.

```
byte[] valueFromTextField = "hello world foo bar".getBytes();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
for (byte element : valueFromTextField) {
    if (i % 4 == 0 && builder.length() > 0) {
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    builder.append(String.format("%02x", element));
    i++;
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Output

```
68656c6c 6f20776f 726c6420 666f6f20 626172
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having **`byte[] bytes`** and you can convert it using **`bytes.toString()`** OR you can change byte by byte

```
byte[] bites = new byte[]{24,4,72,56};

for(int i = 0; i < bites.length; i++)
    System.out.println(new String(bites, i,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String hexadecimals = textField.getText();
hexadecimals = hexadecimals.replaceAll("[^0-9A-Fa-f]", ""); // Remove garbage
int nn = hexadecimals.length();
if (nn % 2 != 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "... must be even", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return "";
}
byte[] bytes = new byte[nn / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < nn - 1; i += 2) {
    int b = Integer.parseInt(hexadecimals.substring(i, i + 2), 16);
    bytes[i] = (byte) b;
}
return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This uses Integer.parseInt with base 16 (0-9A-F) in integer range to ignore negative byte values.

To convert those bytes to text (which in Java is Unicode to hold any combination of chars), one needs to know which text encoding those bytes are in. Here I use UTF-8, which however requires adherance to the UTF-8 multibyte format.